# Angular mat-card-image not working in ios device

Tags: angular-material, mat-card

Angular mat-card-image not working in ios devices. Images aren't showing inside a mat-card on ios browsers. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are they svgs? Could you show a bit of code where you are setting up the images?

Comment: These are **webp** image files. Other types(jpg,png) are working fine but webp files aren't working.

Comment: Up to IOS 13 inclusive webp images were not supported. There were rumours that they would be supported in IOS 14 but I haven't seen the definite info. yet (it must be out there somewhere). What version of IOS are you trying things on? I'll have a try on an IOS device, but I don't think I have 14 yet.

Comment: Found it! Have put up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

IOS 13 and lower do not support webp images.

But according to caniuse (https://caniuse.com/?search=webp) support for webp has come with IOS 14 from 16 September 2020.